# How do I choose a random element from a random array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm a Ruby beginner who's trying to add multiple categories to my hangman game.

I know how to choose a random element from an array. For example:

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
random = animals[rand(animals.length)] 
puts random
```

However, I want to choose an entire array randomly, and then a single random element from that random array. For example:

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
planets = [['jupiter'], ['mars']]
fruits = [['apple'], ['orange'], ['mango']]

categories =[[animals], [planets], [fruits]]

#the code I tried was:
random_array = categories[rand(categories.length)]
random_element = random_array[rand(random_array.length)]
puts random_element
```

But this puts an entire array, instead of one element. Please help! 
Thanks

Comment: Why is each element of `planets` and `fruits` an array and not a string? Why is each element of `categories` within an extra layer of an array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choose unique random number from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562502/choose-unique-random-number-from-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
planets = [['jupiter'], ['mars']]
fruits = [['apple'], ['orange'], ['mango']]

categories = [animals, planets, fruits]
puts categories.sample.sample #=> jupiter
```

As Sawa remarks, this would return either a string or one of the sub-arrays. `*categories.sample.sample` (a splat) always retuns a string.

Comment: You would get `["jupiter"]`, not `"jupiter"`.

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct, but array initialization is not. Here's what you have to do:

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
planets = ['jupiter', 'mars'] 
fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango']

categories = [animals, planets, fruits]
```

In your code, `animals` is array, `planets` and `fruits` are arrays of arrays, and `categories` is array of three arrays, inside of each one is one of you variables

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work, it's your `categories` array that's not working.
It supposed to be:

```
categories =[animals, planets, fruits]
```

and not a mix of arrays within an array.

Answer (score 0):

Why not flatten them all or is that an overkill

```
a = (animals.flatten + fruits.flatten + planets.flatten)
r = a[rand(a.flatten.size)]
=> "dog"
```

You might also use the more efficient `<<` to concatenate arrays.

Comment: `(animals + fruits + planets).flatten` is equivalent, shorter, and likely more performant.

Comment: I would go with `[*animals, *fruits, *planets]`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall `<<` is appending to the array returned by the previous flatten call. While `+` is creating new arrays and pushing all the elements into it. So there are 2 new arrays instead of a single one had we used `<<` (append)

Comment: @sawa Hey that's even more elegant !

Comment: I meant than what you actually had (on line 1), not what you suggest (`<<`). I’m well aware of the differences between `Array#+` & `Array#<<`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Oh. I am a noob. Feel free to correct me anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`Array#sample` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample).

Answer (score 0):

This should be the shortest and cleanest way to do it.

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
planets = [['jupiter'], ['mars']]
fruits = [['apple'], ['orange'], ['mango']]

[animals, planets, fruits].flatten.sample
```

[#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) returns a new array with all elements but in just one dimension.

[#sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) returns one random element from you array