# Choose unique random number from an array

Tags: ruby, random

`b` is the maximum winner that I want.

```
b.times do
  winner = participant[rand(participant.count)]
end
```

I need to generate a unique winner every time. How can I achieve this without making too many changes to this code?

Comment: What is a "maximum winner"?

Comment: maximum number of winners of a contest is stored in b

Comment: @Supertracer so you actually have to pick *b* winners, not a single one. Is that correct?

Comment: @ndn thanks your answer has solved my problem, yes stefan you are correct

Comment: @ndn yeah sure man thanks a ton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already a method for that. Just use [`Array#sample`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample):

```
winners = participants.sample(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#delete_at` which deletes an item at specified index and returns the deleted item.  We can now ensure that item once picked as winner will never be picked again

```
# sample data
participant = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
b = 3

# preserve the original array
p = participant.dup 

# pick winner
b.times do
    winner = p.delete_at(rand(participant.count))
end
```

You can use `Array#sample` (as [ndn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32562581/794242) suggested) if your program is okay to get all winners in one shot